# Cumulative sum by group in sqldf?

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a data frame with 3 variables: place, time, and value (P, T, X). I want to create a fourth variable which will be the cumulative sum of X. Normally I like to do grouping calculations with `sqldf`, but can't seem to find an equivalent for `cumsum`. That is:

```
sqldf("select P,T,X, cumsum(X) as X_CUM from df group by P,T")
```

doesn't work. Is this even possible with `sqldf`? I tried `doBy`, but that doesn't all `cumsum` either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set up some test data:

```
DF <- data.frame(t = 1:4, p = rep(1:3, each = 4), value = 1:12)
```

and now we have three solutions.  First we use [sqldf](http://sqldf.googlecode.com), as requested, using the default SQLite database.  Next we do it with sqldf again but this time with PostgreSQL using [RPostgreSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgreSQL) or [RpgSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RpgSQL) driver.  PostgreSQL supports analytical windowing functions which simplify the SQL.  You will need to set up a PostgreSQL database first to do that one.  Finally we show a pure R solution which only uses the core of R.

**1) sqldf/RSQLite**

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, sum(b.value) as cumsum 
    from DF a join DF b 
    using (p)
    where a.t >= b.t
    group by p, a.t"
)
```

**2) sqldf/RPostgreSQL**

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select *,
    sum(value) over (partition by p order by t) as cumsum 
    from "DF"'
)
```

(This also works with the RpgSQL PostgreSQL driver.  To use that you must have Java installed and a PostgreSQL database set up and then in place of the above use: `1ibrary(RpgSQL); sqldf(...)` where the same SQL string is used except there should be no quotes around `DF`.)

**3) Plain R**

```
transform(DF, cumsum = ave(value, p, FUN = cumsum))
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood what you want:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(P,T), summarize, cumsum(X))
```

does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Or, another option is [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/).

```
> library(data.table)
> DT = data.table(place = 1:4, time = rep(1:3, each = 4), value = 1:3)
> setkey(DT,place,time)   # order by place and time
> DT
      place time value
 [1,]     1    1     1
 [2,]     1    2     2
 [3,]     1    3     3
 [4,]     2    1     2
 [5,]     2    2     3
 [6,]     2    3     1
 [7,]     3    1     3
 [8,]     3    2     1
 [9,]     3    3     2
[10,]     4    1     1
[11,]     4    2     2
[12,]     4    3     3
> DT[,list(time,value,cumsum(value)),by=place]
      place time value V3
 [1,]     1    1     1  1
 [2,]     1    2     2  3
 [3,]     1    3     3  6
 [4,]     2    1     2  2
 [5,]     2    2     3  5
 [6,]     2    3     1  6
 [7,]     3    1     3  3
 [8,]     3    2     1  4
 [9,]     3    3     2  6
[10,]     4    1     1  1
[11,]     4    2     2  3
[12,]     4    3     3  6
>
```